# What is the motive of the universe?

Tags: metaphysics, physics, universe

If you look at the options, the universe is either temporally bounded temporally unbounded is either bounded spatially or unbounded spatially and is any of these permutations with our uncertainty.

However, it is certain as far as my perception is concerned that life exists, if not just mine, but outside my experience and external of my perception.

What exactly is the benefit or motive of the universe to have had an origin to life on earth, or for any other planet that life may have appeared within the cosmos or universe?

Why does physics lead to metaphysics? Unnecessarily? or does metaphysics come before physics?.

Does the universe need an internal observer, and is its motive to be observed ?

Comment: why would it need a motive in the first place?

Comment: Do you have any motive!? You responded to this question and you are a product of the universe so does the universe have a motive you are part of it.?

Comment: I have a motive to understand the question. The universe is not a person so apply to it any will, desire or motivation looks like mere anthropomorphism. Why would any motive be necessary for life to exist in the first place? This is a huge assumption embedded in your question.

Comment: @armand Pansychism? Religion? It's not only me mate. Why is there any observer if everything is just physics? Purpose?

Comment: If you can put up with philosophy/psychology wrapped up deep into fantasy-mythology — like Tolkien or Harry Potter — there is [Beelzebub's Tales to his Grandson](https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Beelzebubs-Tales-to-His-Grandson-by-G-I-Gurdjieff.pdf).
Read Chapters 8 to 14
ie. pdf pages 77 to 105

Answer (score 1):

The Universe doesn't need to have a purpose or a motive- you are trying to attribute ones to it. The Universe doesn't need observers- it seemed to manage perfectly well for billions of years without them, and if we all die today the Universe will not suddenly suffer some crisis as a consequence of our absence. Physics and metaphysics are fields of study practiced by humans- it is a matter of record that metaphysics preceded physics as we currently know it.

Answer (score 0):

You ask whether the universe has a final goal.

Some time ago the same type of question has been asked about the biological evolution on earth. Science did not find out a specific goal.

And on the largest scale, astrophysics did not find a specific goal for the development of the universe as a whole.

As a consequence: Today teleological approaches are banned from science because they did not turn out as a fruitful approach. Instead they invite to speculations based on principles valid for human decision making.

Nevertheless it is a challenging question in cosmology to find out the driving force of [structure formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_formation).

Comment: Is that a fruitfully approach to questions at the expense of the possibility of bitter answers ?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 Do you propose any motive as a candidate?

Comment: I don't want to be evasive I'm just asking questions you have to give me credit for that.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8  I dismiss the teleological question for a motive because the question did not turn out to be fruitful. That’s a different reason than dismissing a question because one is afraid of possible answers. If you criticize this strategy, I would welcome to hear the proposal of a candidate motive.

Answer (score -1):

**Motivation as typically understood is attributed to agents** and is interlinked with action, justification, reason, explanation, and other terms associated with [philosophical agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)). [Motivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation), in fact, is generally studied in depth by psychologists. From the WP article motivation:

> Motivation is an internal state that propels individuals to engage in goal-directed behavior. It is often understood as a force that explains why people or animals initiate, continue, or terminate a certain behavior at a particular time. It is a complex phenomenon and its precise definition is disputed. It contrasts with amotivation, which is a state of apathy or listlessness. Motivation is studied in fields like psychology, motivation science, and philosophy.

Motivation is often connected to an agent's action. (See the SEP article [Reasons for Action](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasons-just-vs-expl/#MotiExplReas) for more information.) **The universe isn't an agent, and to claim otherwise is [anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism)**:

> Anthropomorphism is the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)) It is considered to be an innate tendency of human psychology.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation) Personification is the related attribution of human form and characteristics to abstract concepts such as nations, emotions, and natural forces, such as seasons and weather.

**The universe, other than poetically, does not have motivation.**

Comment: So your saying the universe is not human even though the universe resulted in humanity?

Comment: An oven results in a pizza. Does that fact make an oven a pizza?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition

Comment: Part and whole?

Comment: Humans are a part of the whole universe.